# Step by step of a modification of the Beame-Pitassi Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, satisfiability

I am reading the paper *Measuring the hardness of SAT instances* by Ansótegui, Bonet, Levy and Manyà (Proc. 23rd AAAI Conf. on AI, pp. 222–228, 2008) ([PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZi8d.png)). I am trying to understand the decision algorithm beame_pitassi described in the Figure 1 in paper and showed below. This algorithm searches for the space of an UNSAT formula.

[image]

I am studying that algorithm using the following formula $\Gamma = (a\vee b)(a\vee \lnot b)(\lnot a \vee c)(\lnot a \vee \lnot c)$. Below, the steps using this $\Gamma$.

- function beame_pitassi
- $proved := false$
- $s:= 1$
- while $s \leq 3$ and $\lnot proved$

  - $s = 1$
  - $<false,-> =$ try_strahler($\Gamma$, $1$, $[\,]$)

    - foreach $x \notin [\,]$ and $b \in\{true, false\}$

      - $<false,->=$try_strahler($\Gamma$, $0$, $[a\rightarrow 
        0]$)
      - $<false,->=$try_strahler($\Gamma$, $0$, $[a\rightarrow 
        0, b\rightarrow 
        0]$)
      - $<false,->=$try_strahler($\Gamma$, $0$, $[a\rightarrow 
        0, b\rightarrow 
        0, c\rightarrow 
        0]$)
  - $s = 2$
  - $<true,cut(b,t_1?,t_2?)> =$ try_strahler($\Gamma$, $2$, $[\,]$)

    - foreach $x \notin [\,]$ and $b \in\{true, false\}$

      - $<false,->=$try_strahler($\Gamma$, $1$, $[a\rightarrow 
        0]$)
      - $<true,hypothesis((a+b))>=$try_strahler($\Gamma$, $1$, $[a\rightarrow 
        0, b\rightarrow 
        0]$)
  - $s:=s+1$

I know that the steps of my example could be hard but these say that the algorithm stops when happens the next assignment $[a\rightarrow 
0, b\rightarrow 
0]$ for $\Gamma$. Specifically, when $[a\rightarrow 
0, b\rightarrow 
0]$ falsifies the clause $(a\vee b)$ of $\Gamma$.

For me the output of this example is

$\langle$ unsat, cut(hypothesis($a\vee b$), hypothesis($a\vee\neg b$))$\rangle$.

In other words two clauses ,$(\lnot a \vee c)$ and $(\lnot a \vee \lnot c)$, of $\Gamma$ are losses in the proof, please Is correct the steps that I make in that example? and Could you help to understand why these clauses are losses?

Comment: This is already your fifth question on this paper. You can't expect us to guide you step-by-step in understanding the paper. Make some effort yourself. A good starting point would be getting a thorough background in the area, say by reading lecture notes.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I'm reading background area for one week and still I have this question.

Comment: Perhaps one week is not enough. Some people take a semester-long course in the area. Reading papers is sometimes a very slow activity. Take your time and work things out on your own.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I still do not understand, I make a program of that algorithm in SAGE, and two clauses of the proof are lost, I have edited my question, ...

Comment: LaTeX hint: `\langle ... \rangle`.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I only want to know how the beame_pitassi algorithm above works

Comment: Please don't write "stuff EDIT: more stuff".  Instead, edit the question to be what it should have been from the start, and to read as a single cohesive whole for someone who encounters it for the first time.  You don't need to mark edits by adding "EDIT" -- we have revision history for that.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused by the not very descriptive title. Can you formulate a question in English?

Comment: I have edited my question